# Heroku db:Push - Sequel Adapter NOt Found

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I know there a number of posts similar to this one and yet I still seem to be unable to solve my problem.  So if I have missed something, feel free to explain it like you would to a child. :)

I am trying to push data from my local machine which uses Mysql to Heroku which uses Postgres.

The command `heroku db:push sometable -t` generates the error message below:

```
Failed to connect to database Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError cannot load such file
```

I have also tried:

```
heroku db:push -t sometable mysql://user:password@localhost/db_name
```

Added info:

1. Using Windows 7
2. Using Rails 3.2.8
3. Using Ruby 1.9.3
4. Mysql gem is installed and works with Rails
5. Heroku client is up to date
6. Database is running
7. Heroku db schema is running.
8. Rails was installed with RailsInstaller 1.92

Any suggestions would be greatly appeciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku uses PostgreSQL as database. You should not get this error if you install pg.

Try to run: `gem install pg`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to get it working using standard heroku gem.

I installed Heroku through their site downloader - 'Heroku Toolbelt' package for windows. That didn't work so *in addition* I also installed

`Heroku gem` and all dependencies. (ignore deprecation warning)

`sqlite3 gem` for taps (i don't use sqlite, but heroku needs it)

then it worked!

Comment: Hi Josh - I just received a notice from their Help Desk that Taps is deprecated and that I should use migrations instead.  I'm going to give your way a try though.  Thanks for waiting.

Comment: Hi Again - just tried the suggestions provided by Josh. The problem still remains, unfortunately.  Hm....